# Inline script stops working after form submisssion

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've the following HTML:

```
    <a id="foo">Click Me</a>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('#foo').click(function() {
                alert('hello');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

As you can see, "Click me" works fine until I click the submit button (which reloads the page).

How can I prevent this from happening so that "Click me" works as expected even after form submission?

**Note:** Here's what's inside my `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Update:** I tried removing

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" />` in the `head` tag, it works, however this CSS file is an essential part of Jquery Mobile.

Comment: I don't see how the form reloading the page kills the click event ?

Comment: @rlemon apparently when using Jquery Mobile, it does.

Comment: Anchors should have `href` attribute.

Comment: This is a jQuery Mobile, href is not needed when working with jQM buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possibilities.

You can add attribute **data-ajax="false"** to your form. Because of this your form will act as a normal form. Without it jQuery Mobile will handle form submitting and this is something you don t probably want.

```
<form action="" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Other solution is to change how you bind click event. Instead of your way you should use modern solution like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#foo',function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

One last thing. Unless you know what you are doing don't use this code to bind a click event on DOM ready:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#foo').click(function() {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
```

Unlike pure jQuery, jQuery Mobile uses different logic. This is because when document ready triggers jQuery Mobile page is usually still not fully loaded and enhanced inside a DOM. Because of this jQM developers have created page events. If you want to find more read my other answer about that topic: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

For:

```
   <input type="button" value="submit">
```

Tell me that this is.. :D